# What is the purpose of `complete` argument?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

Some jQuery animation methods take an argument described as `complete`, which is a function that is to be called once the animation is done. For example:

```
$(obj).slideUp(duration, easing, complete());
```

How is this different from calling `complete` after the animation as below?

```
$(obj).slideUp(duration, easing)
.complete();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(obj).slideUp(duration, easing, complete());
```

This is wrong. This is calling `complete` *before* `slideUp` is even called.

```
$(obj).slideUp(duration, easing);
complete();
```

This executes `slideUp` and immediately afterwards calls `complete`. The `slideUp` animation may not  (in fact, surely *will not*) yet be finished by the time `complete` is called.

```
$(obj).slideUp(duration, easing, function () {
    alert('Complete!');
});

// or

$(obj).slideUp(duration, easing, complete);
                                     // ^^ look ma, no () !
```

Now *this* is how you're supposed to use it. "Complete!" will be alerted after and only after the `slideUp` animation has finished.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is that in the second case the `complete` is called immediatly after the animation **starts**, while passing it as callback triggers it at animation **end**.

The animation can in fact be asyncronous, so the javascript execution continues after you launch the animation, hence immediately calling `complete()` after `$(obj).slideUp(duration, easing);` does **not** guarantee that the `complete` call will be executed after the animation is completed, only after it started.

Also

```
$(obj).slideUp(duration, easing, complete());
```

should really be

```
$(obj).slideUp(duration, easing, complete);
```

In fact in the first case you're calling the `complete` function even **before** the animation starts!

Lastly, mind that the second example seems wrong:

```
$(obj).slideUp(duration, easing)
.complete();
```

This is chaining a call to `slideUp` with a call to `complete` but jquery object have no `complete` method. It should probably be:

```
$(obj).slideUp(duration, easing);
complete();
```

As it actually was in a previous edit of the question.

Comment: shouldn't it be `$(obj).slideUp(duration, easing, function(){ complete()});`

Comment: That is the exactly same thing.

Comment: I remember it used to run immediately unless you wrapped it in a function.

Comment: Only if you actually **call** it by writing `complete()` instead of passing only the `complete` name.

Comment: You're welcome :) but please see my last edit. Also, if my answer helped you, fell free to upvote it and/or accept it as correct answer.